error install another postgres version on windows
I already have version 11 installed, I tried to install v15 but I get this error (https://i.sstatic.net/X4YPuscg.png)
I already uninstall v11, delete all registry, and delete directory in program files/postgresql with thought I can completely remove it and install from the beginning. but now I can't even install 1 version (the error still the same)

I'll vote to close this, like the many other identical questions. You have to pester EnterpriseDB to fix the bug in their installer. Ideally, reply to the thread on the pgsql-hackers mailing list and describe your exact environment.
